# Elastic Cache stuck in creating state

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elasticache

I tried to create two Memcache cluster's in Elastic Cache Using Elastic Beanstalk in AWS. Both got stuck in the same state saying 'creating' for the past 3 hrs.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did your issue get fixed? Did it succeed? If not what error did you get?

Comment: im sorry i forgot to update .the issue got resolved on its own after nearly 4 hours .It seems we cant manually stop the process.

Answer (score 2):

I also faced the same issue yesterday while creating **2** Redis clusters using terraform at the same time.

It got resolved when created one more Redis cluster in the same region using AWS console.

**Note**: There seems to be an issue with creating multiple Custers at the same time the same region/AZ.